# How does MongoDB offload logic and processing to the client?

Tags: mongodb

I was looking at Kristina's book and at the very beginning of the intro chapter I read that MongoDB offloads logic and processing to the client side whenever possible.

Can someone please explain this in more detail?

When it says whenever possible, what is this "when"? And how does it determine if it is possible?

And also about processing and logic... what are some examples? Like an insert or update being done client side and not server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors are describing one of the MongoDB design principles.

Here are some of the ways MongoDB offloads processing to the client:

- Object IDs are usually generated and provided by the client
- Since Mongo is schema-free, the client is responsible for ensuring that all the required fields are present and contain valid data (notable exception: constraining unique indexes)
- There are no joins: such aggregation often needs to be done by the client
- Aggregate functions are severely limited (though there are some more coming in v2.2)

Neither inserts, updates, nor any of the like are processed by the client in any significant way.